# Connect BindingNavigator with Programmatically Created Datagridview

Tags: c#, binding, datagridview

I have created a datagridview programmatically.
So there is no bindingsource or datasource that we can connect both of the Datagridview and Binidgnavigator to them.
Is there any other way to connect them to each other.
Here is my code for datafridview

Help me to connect it to a bindingNavigator

```
private void Fill()
{
    try
    {
        if (dataGridView1 != null)
        {
            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 11;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = Resources.Form1_Fill_ID;
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = Resources.Form1_Fill_Family;
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = Resources.Form1_Fill_Cellphone;
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = Resources.Form1_Fill_Phone1;
            dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = Resources.Form1_Fill_Phone2;
            dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = Resources.Form1_Fill_Phone3;
            dataGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText = Resources.Form1_Fill_Fax;
            dataGridView1.Columns[7].HeaderText = Resources.Form1_Fill_CompanyName;
            dataGridView1.Columns[8].HeaderText = Resources.Form1_Fill_Agency;
            dataGridView1.Columns[9].HeaderText = Resources.Form1_Fill_Brands;
            dataGridView1.Columns[10].HeaderText = Resources.Form1_Fill_Address;

            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = Resources.Form1_Fill_ID;
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = Resources.Form1_Fill_Family;
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = Resources.Form1_Fill_Cellphone;
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = Resources.Form1_Fill_Phone1;
            dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = Resources.Form1_Fill_Phone2;
            dataGridView1.Columns[5].Name = Resources.Form1_Fill_Phone3;
            dataGridView1.Columns[6].Name = Resources.Form1_Fill_Fax;
            dataGridView1.Columns[7].Name = Resources.Form1_Fill_CompanyName;
            dataGridView1.Columns[8].Name = Resources.Form1_Fill_Agency;
            dataGridView1.Columns[9].Name = Resources.Form1_Fill_Brands;
            dataGridView1.Columns[10].Name = Resources.Form1_Fill_Address;
        }

        _conn.ConnectionString = _connectionString;
        var cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from contacts ", _conn);
        _conn.Open();
        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        int i = 0;
        while (reader != null && reader.Read())
        {
            if (dataGridView1 != null)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);
            }
            if (dataGridView1 != null)
            {
                var row = dataGridView1.Rows[i];

                row.Cells[Resources.Form1_Fill_ID].Value = reader[0].ToString();
                row.Cells[Resources.Form1_Fill_Family].Value = reader[1].ToString();
                row.Cells[Resources.Form1_Fill_Cellphone].Value = reader[2].ToString();
                row.Cells[Resources.Form1_Fill_Phone1].Value = reader[3].ToString();
                row.Cells[Resources.Form1_Fill_Phone2].Value = reader[4].ToString();
                row.Cells[Resources.Form1_Fill_Phone3].Value = reader[5].ToString();
                row.Cells[Resources.Form1_Fill_Fax].Value = reader[6].ToString();
                row.Cells[Resources.Form1_Fill_CompanyName].Value = reader[7].ToString();
                row.Cells[Resources.Form1_Fill_Agency].Value = reader[8].ToString();
                row.Cells[Resources.Form1_Fill_Brands].Value = reader[9].ToString();
                row.Cells[Resources.Form1_Fill_Address].Value = reader[10].ToString();

            }
            i++;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return;
    }
    finally
    {
        _conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to revise your code. You don't need to create a column programmactically, your *query* itself could create a column through `DataTable` to `BindingSource`, try this code and get some idea.

**BindingNavigator and BindingSource**

```
        string connectionString =
            @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
            @"Data Source=D:\myDatabase.accdb;";

        string queryString = "SELECT Name AS FullName, Gender AS Gender, Address AS [Current Address] FROM Person";

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection))
        {
            try
            {
                BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
                OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(queryString, connection);
                OleDbCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                bs.DataSource = dataTable;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
                bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = bs;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```